# No server.conf but Openvpn Access Server works fine on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: configuration, vpn, vps, openvpn

I was successfully able to install and run OpenVPN Access server (2.8.3) on my VPS hosting. I am using the GUI access server.

I am able to connect and securely browse through the internet using OpenVPN client on macOS.

The problem I seek solution to is that I am not able to find the server.conf file on my server for the OpenVPN and yet everything works great!

I have searched the system for the file using (find) and yet no luck.

why is that happening? even the sample files are not configured, is there a default config file embedded someplace else?

Comment: Have you checked `/etc/openvpn` ?

Comment: Yeah, that's why the question.